# What is the purpose of Airbnb's meta content JSON?

Tags: javascript, html

my guess would be so that it can be rendered as part of the view without generating code.
maybe other reasons?

`<meta content="{&quot;packages/field_guide.bundle.js&quot;:&quot;https://z2.muscache.com/airbnb/static/packages/field_guide.bundle-22d94f5ab05ba22407948606faac3322.js&quot;,&quot;packages/airlock_modal.bundle.js&quot;:&quot;https://z0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/packages/airlock_modal.bundle-c15ad0374f31c315b1cc5dd857ed9efe.js&quot;,&quot;packages/airlock_inline.bundle.js&quot;:&quot;https://z1.muscache.com/airbnb/static/packages/airlock_inline.bundle-9805923b4b7bf6c4a74ba60867b5c479.js&quot;,&quot;packages/profile_pic_upsell.js&quot;:&quot;https://z0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/packages/profile_pic_upsell-1e37b543f244b7b06a98a5bb2761b14f.js&quot;,&quot;packages/reset_password_modal.bundle.js&quot;:&quot;https://z0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/packages/reset_password_modal.bundle-f8edbf559a909e91c4f6c643b3d1c465.js&quot;}" id="_bootstrap-javascript_paths">`